# cURL request works fine locally but isn't returning any data on the remote server

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-8, guzzle

I have a Laravel 8.x application that does a php cURL request on a cronjob to pull in some data from the EA.com website for the FIFA 22 videogame - it has recently stopped working for some reason, when I try this using the same codebase on my local machine it all works fine. However when I try this using my live app on a remote server it no longer returns the expected data (on a LEMP stack Digital Ocean droplet).

I cannot be sure if EA are blocking my requests but I'm just trying to figure out what I can do next as I only get an issue

```
    private function doExternalApiCall($endpoint = null, $params = [])
    {
        $url = $this->apiUrl . $endpoint . http_build_query($params);
        // e.g $url = https://proclubs.ea.com/api/fifa/clubs/matches?matchType=gameType9&platform=ps5&clubIds=310718
        dump($url);

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3,    // i have tried experimenting with other numbers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
              'accept: application/json', 
              'Referer: https://www.ea.com/',
            ),
          ));

          if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
          {
              echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
          }
          else
          {
              echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
          }          

          if(curl_errno($curl))
          {
              echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
          } 
          
          $response = curl_exec($curl);
          curl_close($curl);

          dump($response);  // should return json data but on live it returns false
          return $response;
    }
```

// Expected output in the terminal when the cronjob is run on live (this is what I see when running from my local machine)

```
"https://proclubs.ea.com/api/fifa/clubs/matches?matchType=gameType9&platform=ps5&clubIds=310718"
"[{"matchId":"9798251730479","timestamp":1636584075,"timeAgo":{"number":2,"unit":"days"},"clubs":...... <more json data>
```

// Actual behaviour when cronjob is run on live site

```
"https://proclubs.ea.com/api/fifa/clubs/matches?matchType=gameType9&platform=ps5&clubIds=310718"
false
```

[image: Running cronjob on my local machine]

[image: Running cronjob on my remote server at proclubs.app]

When running this on my local - the response is instant and returns the expected data, where on live the requests are taking slightly longer and it returns `FALSE`

Any suggestions on what I should do next?

-- update --
I have added the additional lines to get the curl error and I get the following:

```
Curl error: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes receivedCurl error: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `curl_error`,  `curl_errno`, and `curl_getinfo`

Comment: @AleksanderWons have added the curl error - I have a feeling the ea.com is just blocking me :(

Comment: Either that or your server blocks connection to that domain. Either way, there is not much you can do here, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can try some more debugging from the command line, SSH in and simply try `curl -v https://your-url/`.  `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` - you don't need this for a GET, remove it.  Have you tried removing the fake `Referer` header, maybe they can detect that it is being faked and block bcs of that? Specifying a blank  `CURLOPT_ENCODING` also seems dodgy, why are you doing that? Remove it. Is there a reason you're specifying `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'll literally just copied the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` from another page i'll remove it as it likely serves no purpose for, similarly the same for the `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` i'll see if this makes any difference and let you know how I get on